# <a> tags inside switch statement arn't working in React/Next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, switch-statement

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here. I get the sense I'm not meant to use a tags to link out to an external website outside of the return statement, but just wanted some clarification on how I should set this up? I also am getting a warning case about a fallthrough case in Switch. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const StreamingButtons: React.FC<Props> = ({appleMusicUrl, spotifyUri}) => {

  const handleExternalDownload = (service: StreamingType) => {
    switch (service) {
      case StreamingType.APPLEMUSIC: {
        <a href={appleMusicUrl}></a>
      }
      case StreamingType.SPOTIFY : {
        <a href={spotifyUri}></a>
     }
      default : {
        console.log("do nothing")
  } 
}
}

return (
    <div className='streamingButtons'>
        <img 
            className="appleImg"
            src='/images/streaming-transparent/apple-music.png'
            onClick={() => handleExternalDownload(StreamingType.APPLEMUSIC)}
        />
        <img
          className='spotifyImg'
          src='/images/streaming-transparent/spotify-green.svg'
          onClick={() => handleExternalDownload(StreamingType.SPOTIFY)}

        />
      </div>
)
}

export default StreamingButtons
```

Comment: You need `break` statements, you're getting fallthrough on your `case`s.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean to accomplish with the JSX in the `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't looking to `return` an `a` tag. It does not automatically invoke the download behavior. What you're really doing is making the image a link to direct to a particular `href` right? Wrap each `img` with an `a` tag and change your function to create the appropriate `href`

```js
const StreamingButtons: React.FC<Props> = ({ appleMusicUrl, spotifyUri }) => {
    const getDownloadUrl = (service: StreamingType) => {
        switch (service) {
            case StreamingType.APPLEMUSIC: {
                return appleMusicUrl
            }
            case StreamingType.SPOTIFY: {
                return spotifyUri
            }
            default: {
                const NO_BEHAVIOR = '\\'
                return NO_BEHAVIOR
            }
        }
        return (
            <div className='streamingButtons'>
                <a href={getDownloadUrl(StreamingType.APPLEMUSIC)}>
                    <img
                        className="appleImg"
                        src='/images/streaming-transparent/apple-music.png'
                    />
                </a>
                <a href={getDownloadUrl(StreamingType.SPOTIFY)}>
                    <img
                        className='spotifyImg'
                        src='/images/streaming-transparent/spotify-green.svg'
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the markup please try below , note the brackets. Other vise can you post the error

```
case StreamingType.APPLEMUSIC: (
        <a href={appleMusicUrl}></a>
      )
```